# System apps missing fonts after update to 19.10

Tags: fonts, 19.10

After update to 19.10 I noticed that Calculator and System Monitor are missing fonts. [screenshot from system monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOIvA.png)
Other than that they seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean font cache:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/fontconfig/*
rm ~/.cache/fontconfig/*
fc-cache -r
```